# Minima of variable stars

Tags: variable-star

There's a [handy website](https://skyandtelescope.org/observing/the-minima-of-algol/) showing the minima of Algol. Is there such a website for other variable stars? Or could you give me a code for computing the minimum of a variable star?

Comment: If the variable star is *periodic* then it might be something one can do with pencil and paper or a calculator. You might consider mentioning a few variable stars for which you'd be interested in predicting. Just a thought.

Comment: Maybe this? http://astro.ago.uni-lj.si/calc_var_min.html

Comment: Check out the American Association of Variable Star Observers (www.aavso.org).  They have lots of data and tutorials.  But, since stars are variable for different reasons, there is no generalized solution.

Comment: @DialFrost what name is supposed to be entered there? I didn't manage to make it to find anything :D

Comment: Sorry i should have checked before posting, im not sure either XD

Comment: @uhuh for example the 12 stars mentioned in this article: https://skyandtelescope.org/observing/celestial-objects-to-watch/the-top-12-naked-eye-variable-stars/